# poplib error with 3.3 not 2.7: Invalid message number

Tags: python, python-2.7, email-attachments, python-3.3

I am getting an error from code using `poplib` on Python 3.3 but which works on Python 2.7:

```
poplib.error_proto: b"-ERR Invalid message number: b'1'"
```

**I want to migrate to python 3.3** because I have a specific module that is only installed on my python 3.3.

I am learning the python programming language.

Here is the sample that succeeds on python 2.7, but this sample code does not work on my python 3.3.

```
import poplib

pop_server = 'mail01.org'
user = 'user'
password = 'pass'

p = poplib.POP3(pop_server)
p.user(user)
p.pass_(password)

print ("This mailbox has %d messages, totaling %d bytes." % p.stat())

msg_list = p.list()
print (msg_list)

for msg in msg_list[1]:
    msg_num, _ = msg.split()
    resp = p.retr(msg_num)
```

Here is the output:

```
This mailbox has 2 messages, totaling 633300 bytes.
(b'+OK 2 messages:', [b'1 137956', b'2 495344'], 20)
```

Here is the error traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "AttachmentDownloader.py", line 28, in <module>
    resp = p.retr(msg_num)
  File "C:\Python33\lib\poplib.py", line 236, in retr
    return self._longcmd('RETR %s' % which)
  File "C:\Python33\lib\poplib.py", line 171, in _longcmd
    return self._getlongresp()
  File "C:\Python33\lib\poplib.py", line 147, in _getlongresp
    resp = self._getresp()
  File "C:\Python33\lib\poplib.py", line 140, in _getresp
    raise error_proto(resp)
poplib.error_proto: b"-ERR Invalid message number: b'1'"
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [ask] particularly how to create a [mcve].

Comment: How do you know it doesn't work? What's the minimum code to still get the error.

Comment: @PeterWood i already try it, 

resp = p.retr(msg_num) 

it would works on python 2.7 but not works on python 3.3. have you try?

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: @Selcuk poplib.error_proto: b"-ERR Invalid message number: b'1'"

Comment: hardcode it with value, encode it with utf=8 encode with ascii it doesn't work at all

Comment: Most of the code in the loop is unneeded for this example. And most of the imports. Make it as small as possible to avoid distractions and make it as easy as possible for others to trouble-shoot.

Comment: @PeterWood yeah, thanks for the advice, i will do it in my next question if any. this is my first time write question. thanks :)

Comment: @ADityaBimantara I've improved the question a little.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to pass a `str` as message number. Change the following line

```
msg_num, _ = msg.split()
```

to

```
msg_num = int(msg.split()[0])
```

Comment: yeah it works, 
then my if not works if resp[0].startswith('+OK'): also email.message_from_string('\n'.join(resp[1])) this is not works, is there any alternative?

Comment: @ADityaBimantara ask a new question if you've not been able to find an answer

Comment: @PeterWood helloo,, already solved, thanks :)

if i want share my final code that can download the email attachment in python 3.3, where should i write?